# Is there a way to parse excel in Oracle Blob column to read the content in the file?

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, xpath, plsql

I have a Table ABC with Column 'record' as Blob with excel files. I have two kinds of excel templates, lets say Student Excel file and Teacher Excel file.

Is there a  way to write a SQL script, to read each row and determine if it is either Student or Staff template by reading the contents inside? Please help

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not that these are `BLOB`s, but that they are Excel. That's a third party format and you will need an API to read the Excel document.

The good news is that the [alexandria-plsql-utils](https://github.com/mortenbra/alexandria-plsql-utils) package on GitHub is a collection of utilities, one of which is `ooxml_util_pkg`. It can read and write Office Open XML (.xlsx, .docx, etc.) files.

There may well be other libraries for this sort of thing, but this is the one I've used.